# My postinst script launches a service successfully but apt-get apparently shuts it down. Why?

Tags: apt, application-development, services

I have this package with a postinst script that launches a service as its last step.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
[...]
case "$1" in
   configure)
    [...]
    ldconfig
    echo "Install concluded"
    echo "Starting service"
    service lttng-sessiond restart
    echo "Postinst complete"
   ;;
   [...]
esac
exit 0
```

When I run 'sudo apt-get install packagename', I get this piece of log:

```
[...]
Starting service
stop: Unknown instance:
lttng-sessiond start/running, process 22914
Postinst complete
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

The "stop: Unknown instance:" is due to my using 'restart' instead of 'start', no big deal.  The important thing is that the service *does* start, as the log shows.  But the System Monitor reveals the service dies almost instantaneously (it's not a problem with the service itself, since issuing the service start command anew from the command line works just fine).

I'm grasping at straws at this point: could it be the "libc-bin triggers" or the "ldconfig deferred processing" that is shutting the service down?

Comment: I've resurrected this as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716481/baffling-debian-installation-script-service-starts-but-then-quits-mysteriously

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been answered on the cross-posted [SO] post^

Comment: I agree. Close this.